# Where does R' Kook refer to secular Zionism as Moshiach ben Yosef?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, zionism, abraham-isaac-kook

In [this article](https://mizrachi.org/hamizrachi/the-messianic-process-of-modern-israel/) Dr. Polonsky talks about R' Kook's identification of secular Zionism as Moshiach ben Yosef, but he doesn't quote the source. Can someone point me to where R' Kook discusses this?

Comment: Probably a reference to Rav Kook's eulogy of Herzl. See the Wiki page https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9D) and this English translation https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=30&id=1037

Comment: Also reproduced in Ma’amarei Rayah I [Jerusalem 5740/1980] pp. 94-99

Comment: What is presented in the article is not using precise, traditional language. Dr. Polonsky says that Moshiach ben Yosef & Moshiach ben David pertain to "time periods" and specific individuals. This is actually incorrect. Like is taught explicitly by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato, the terms used to refer to the "time periods" of Moshiach ben Yosef & Moshiach ben David are called the Pekidah (for ben Yosef's time) and the Zechirah (for ben David's time). Rav Kook connects the establishment of the state of Israel to the time period of the Pekidah. This is also the traditional teaching.

Comment: R Kook did not say that. He only said that Herzl had the spirit of מבי. The quote has been misappropriated

Comment: Sanhedrin 98b. Cf. Rabbi A.I. Hakohen Kook, Orot (Jerusalem: Mossad Harav Kook,
5745/1985), p. 80; Bezalel Naor trans., Orot (Northvale, NJ: Jason Aronson, 1993), p.
188.?       https://www.machonso.org/uploads/images/13-D-10-lamentation.pdf

Comment: @Miguel Thanks, there it is on page 10. If you can post as an answer I can credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 10 here.

Sanhedrin 98b. Cf. Rabbi A.I. Hakohen Kook, Orot (Jerusalem: Mossad Harav Kook, 5745/1985), p. 80; Bezalel Naor trans., Orot (Northvale, NJ: Jason Aronson, 1993), p. 188. [machonso.org/uploads/images/13-D-10-lamentation.pdf](https://machonso.org/uploads/images/13-D-10-lamentation.pdf)

Comment: @Yehuda Thank you for the points!

Comment: I think it should be added that he only says "footsteps". Otherwise I feel this quote is being misused.